# Device ID Confusion and SIGNATURE_INVALID

Tags: android, tizen

**TL;DR;**

1. What is the difference between the Device ID returned by "sdb devices" and the value shown in Tizen IDE's "Request a device profile" screen.
2. How can I generate the same Device ID (shown in the Tizen IDE) from a CLI without needing to have the entire IDE installed?

**A little background:**

I have a Tizen web app project I'm loading on my Gear 2 Neo, which works well.  I have a coworker over in China with horrible internet and he needs to do a demo with this development build on his own Gear 2 Neo, which I've been fighting with.

I don't think installing the IDE on his machine to retrieve this value will be possible due to the extremely slow internet.  If I can get the correct Device ID, I think I could get this to work without an issue.  I'm not able to do any screensharind with him either (again, speed) so that pretty much leaves me with emails and phone communication.

When we run 'sdb install file.wgt' on the laptop with the device attached, the following error gets generated:

```
__return_cb req_id[1] pkg_type[wgt] pkgid[0st4vaBAfj] key[install_percent] val[33]
__return_cb req_id[1] pkg_type[wgt] pkgid[0st4vaBAfj] key[error] val[22]
__return_cb req_id[1] pkg_type[wgt] pkgid[0st4vaBAfj] key[end] val[fail]
processing result : SIGNATURE_INVALID [22] failed
spend time for pkgcmd is [2891]ms
```

Tizen IDE generates a DUID like: `H/inEM1/zJwF6xXXXXXXyucFBM=`

The one that 'sdb devices' returns is like: `53b441434000000`

I've tried many of the common suggestions in regards to the SIGNATURE_INVALID error:

- Remove or edit the certificate-registration.xml
- Clean the project, and remove the .metadata folder in the workspace
- Regenerated the certs/device-profile.xml/etc
- Validated the USB Debugging checkbox is checked on both devices

I'm very new to the Android and Tizen SDKs, and I think I'm just confusing myself.  I believe it's not the correct format for the Device ID, and that is the cause of my issues.

My questions are: Am I correct that the ID from 'sdb devices' is the wrong one?  Is there a command line interface for retrieving the correct one (the one that the IDE returns)?

-Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For No.2 unfortunately, need installing sdb tool at least.
duid can get from sdb command line

$ sdb shell /opt/etc/duid-gadget

to install his device, generate new certificate-registration.xml and re-build the demo application.
then push the xml to the /home/developer/ on his device and try to install the application.

Comment: Thank you, I finally had a chance to revisit this (his demo in China was unsuccessful due to the rushing of it and my lack of understanding with the device IDs).  This is great to know, and I have yet to find anywhere else on the web that explains this.  If you Google "Tizen Device IDs from Command Line" or something, everything mentions "sdb devices"!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. “sdb devices” returns serial number of devices. That is just created by sdb and it is used to distinguish device to connect using sdb. This is not the DUID.